# Git: Ignore changes to file on specific branch

Tags: git

For a personal project, I have two branches, one public and one private.  I have one file (call `a.b`) that I will be updating regularly on my private branch, but when I merge the private branch onto the public branch, I don't want `a.b` updated.  Is there a way to do this?

A branch specific `git update-index --skip-worktree a.b` command would be ideal, but from what I can tell, this command propagates to all branches.

Comment: `git merge <name-of-branch> --no-commit --no-ff` then restore the file `a.b`?

Comment: If you make it into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try merging without the automatic commit, and then make the appropriate changes to a specific file before finalising the merge commit.

Step 1:

Merge without the commit (no-ff so git doesn't just move the branch).

```bash
git merge <name-of-branch> --no-commit --no-ff
```

Step 2:

Restore the file

```bash
git restore --source=<name-of-other-branch> a.b
```

Step 3:

Commit the merge (make sure to write an appropriate message)

```bash
git commit
```